# What is the mathematical logic of question ban?

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban

How does the algorithm get an account question banned?

I wonder if anyone knows for example how many down votes you must have to get banned, or how many non-answered questions? Does it consider questions marked as duplicates or off topic?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are details that we do not share, very much on purpose.

We believe that if these were out, some people will game them - being happy to skirt close to a ban without actually hitting it.

We'd rather people not know the exact details so they don't feel comfortable to ask bad questions at any time knowing they will not get into a ban for it.

Comment: Okay no problem, I just want to get out of that ban.

Comment: @onix You were given a page with a link to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), were you not?  Read the post in its entirety.

Comment: @Onix fair... however, do you need to know exactly how many votes shy of the threshold you are? Not really. All that is important is you need to improve Qs.... whether it's one vote or 17...